# How to deploy Docker Image from Docker Hub to Azure ACS?

Tags: asp.net, azure, docker, containers, continuous-deployment

I'm new to Azure Container Services(ACS) . I have ASP.NET site I need to deploy from Docker Hub to ACS. IS it any easiest way to deploy from Docker Hub?

Comment: You mean Amazon ECS?

Comment: No.I need to deploy on  Azure Container Services(ACS)

Comment: Ahh, my brain just read 'A' and 'z' in Azure but translated it to Amazon, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the detailed requirements, but there is the possibility to deploy WebApps (as you said you have ASP.NET site) directly from Docker Hub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image.

Alternatively, you could maybe use Azure Container Registry to register and manage your containers over there...